# JOINing four tables together

Tags: mysql, join

I have four tables, `categories`, `category_permissions`, `category_relation`, and `documents`.

It's a part of a documentation project I'm working on, just to learn more about relational databases.

Pseudo data for the example tables:

**Categories**

```
id | name             
-----------------------
 1 | Default Category
```

**Category Permissions**

```
category_id | permission_id 
-----------------------------
1           | 1
1           | 2
```

**Category Relation**

```
document_id | category_id 
---------------------------
1           | 1
2           | 1
```

**Documents**

```
id | title            | content
--------------------------------------
1  | Sample Document  | Content!!!!!
2  | Another Document | Hello, World!
```

What I'm trying to get is rows returned containing information using all of the tables combined. Right now I can get either all of the information surrounding the document (document table, joined with the relation and category tables) or only information surrounding the permissions.

I suspect the issue is because the category permissions aren't directly related to the documents that this is happening.

Something like this is what I'm expecting:

```
id | title            | content       | category_id | permission_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Sample Document  | Content!!!!!! | 1           | 1
1  | Sample Document  | Content!!!!!! | 1           | 2
2  | Another Document | Hello, world! | 1           | 1
2  | Another Document | Hello, world! | 1           | 2
```

But I'm getting more like this:

```
id | title            | content       | category_id | permission_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Sample Document  | Content!!!!!! | 1           | (NULL)
1  | Sample Document  | Content!!!!!! | 1           | (NULL)
2  | Another Document | Hello, world! | 1           | (NULL)
2  | Another Document | Hello, world! | 1           | (NULL)
```

Here's what I think the query should be, and like I mentioned it works how I expect except the permission id's return null.

```
SELECT d.id, d.title, d.content, c.id, cp.permission_id
FROM documents d
LEFT JOIN category_relation cr ON cr.document_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN category_permissions cp ON cp.category_id = cr.category_id
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = cr.category_id;
```

If I switch the second `LEFT JOIN category_permissions` to a `RIGHT JOIN`, that is when the data flips and I get the permissions, but not the documents.

My question is, am I structuring my data wrong, or lacking the know-how in MySQL to pull this off? I *could* just pull all of the documents and then loop through them to query for their categories and permissions, but putting queries in loops has never worked out for me performance-wise, especially when trying it against larger sets of data.

Comment: No, the query you show - with these data - would not give you NULLs there. Something is different to what you show here

Answer (score 2):

If the structure is not giving you any other grief, then you could just "tighten" the query a bit, in order to get the result that you want.

Using the following test table / data:

```
create table categories
as select 1, 'Default Category' from dual ;

create table categorypermissions
as
select 1 category_id, 1 permission_id from dual
union select 1, 2 from dual;

create table categoryrelation
as
select 1 document_id, 1 category_id from dual
union select 2, 1 from dual;

create table documents
as 
select 1 id, 'Sample Document' title, 'Content!!!!!' content from dual
union select 2, 'Another Document', 'Hello, World!' from dual;
```

This query seems to be doing the trick:

```
select
  D.id
, D.title
, D.content
, CR.category_id
, CP.permission_id
from documents D
  join categoryrelation CR on D.id = CR.document_id
  join categorypermissions CP on CP.category_id = CR.category_id 
order by D.id, CP.permission_id
; 

-- output:
+----+------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
| id | title            | content       | category_id | permission_id |
+----+------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
|  1 | Sample Document  | Content!!!!!  |           1 |             1 |
|  1 | Sample Document  | Content!!!!!  |           1 |             2 |
|  2 | Another Document | Hello, World! |           1 |             1 |
|  2 | Another Document | Hello, World! |           1 |             2 |
+----+------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(MySQL 5.7)

[Dbfiddle here.](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ba2c313e04d2d650077cba73a4c6497c)